# How do I prevent xcode from editing the code

Tags: xcode

Xcode lately is rewriting some code source,
say empty function on occation is rewritten as {}, etc. It's absolutely infuriating.
How to prevent xcode from editing the code behind my back?

Comment: Do you happen to have automatic code formatting (with a tool like SwiftFormat) as one of your build steps?

Comment: Argh, TL says we do. Do be sure to have an answer to get upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often a side effect of an automatic code formatting.

Tools like [SwiftFormat](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat) often get invoked as a build step before compilation to ensure consistent code formatting among all team members.

Another drawback of this method is a lost undo history when a file gets reformatted, but from my experience, pros of autoformatting outweigh the cons even in a one person team.

Comment: I'm curious what are the pros of autoformatting ?

Comment: In theory, the pros would be consistent formatting, automatically enforced. But in practice I prefer a combination of SwiftLint and human beings (I do like the conventions that SwiftLint can make you obey).

Comment: It ensures that the source code is formatted uniformly across all the codebase, thus saving time during code reviews and eliminating a potential source of tension due to different code style preferences among team members. It also reduces cognitive load when writing the code: often it's very convenient not to indent a piece of code too precisely, knowing that the formatter will take care of that as soon as I build the project.